# CouchDB deleting and recreating document gives conflict

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-nano

I need to recreate a document in CouchDB. I use `nano` package, but I think the problem is the same with API calls.
What I'm currently doing is to make two calls:

```
await dbHandle.bulk({docs: [{_id: "abc", _rev: "12-aaaa", _deleted: true}]});
await dbHandle.bulk({docs: [{_id: "abc", content: "...."}]});
```

But if I combine the two calls into one, the creation gives conflict:

```
await dbHandle.bulk({docs: [{_id: "abc", _rev: "12-aaaa", _deleted: true},
                            {_id: "abc", content: "...."}]});
```

But shouldn't the document be created with a different `_rev` value, so no conflict?

I agree that the difference between the two methods is minor, but I want to understand how deletions are synchronized. I have few problems during testing that seems caused by delete operations continuing in background somehow. Sure I'm doing something wrong, but I need to be sure.

Thanks for enlighten me!
mario

Comment: When a document is marked _deleted the allDocs index is affected.  I believe you are getting a conflict because the index has not been updated for the deletion at the time the new document with the same _id is processed.